# jsp getting filenames from directory

Tags: jsp

I'm sure this is simple but I'm usually in PHP and having some difficulty getting used to JSP. I just need the filenames but I get the error listed below

```
 File jsp = new File("/home/www/contents/testing/images/thing");

 String f = "";

 File[] list = jsp.listFiles();

 for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++)
 {

    f = list[i].split("/");

    out.println(f[6]);

 }
```

tomcat error:

```
The method split(String) is undefined for the type File
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html). The `File` class does not have the `split()` method. This is exactly what the compilation error is trying to tell you. You're liklely confusing it with [the `String` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) which has indeed a `split()` method.

If you want to get the file name, just use the `getName()` method of the `File` class.

```
f = list[i].getName();
out.println(f);
```

Note that this problem has nothing to do with JSP. It's all just basic Java. You'd have had exactly the same problem when doing so in a plain Java application with a `main()` method instead of a JSP file (which by the way allows for much easier fiddling/unittesting than a JSP file).